# Setting the goal in TrajectoryPlannerROS

Tags: ros, navigation, actionlib, motion-planners, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been going through the API's in TrajectoryPlannerROS from  [here](https://dev.bdm.cc/rosdoc/base_local_planner/html/classbase__local__planner_1_1TrajectoryPlannerROS.html)  and in the ROS wiki. But I haven't been able to figure  **out how to  set the goal pose?**  I can't make this out anywhere in the documentation, despite there being lots of functions related to the goal, such as isGoalReached.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10305/setting-the-goal-in-trajectoryplannerros/) by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 365 on 2011-06-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The navigation stack uses [actionlib](http://www.ros.org/wiki/actionlib) to set the 2D nav goal pose. [This tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals) explains how to do that programatically. For debugging, it is often useful to [set navigation goals using RViz](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/UserGuide#A2D_Nav_Goal_.28Keyboard_shortcut:_g.29).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2